# Continually running PHP script using Bash

Tags: php, bash, scripting, memory-leaks

I have a long running PHP script that has a memory leak which causes it to fail part way through.  The script uses a 3rd party library and I haven't been able to find the source of the leak.

What I would like to do is create a bash script that continually runs the PHP script, processing 1000 records at a time, until the script returns an exit code saying it has finished processing all records.  I figure this should help me get around the memory leak because the script would run for 1000 records, exit, and then a new process would be started for another 1000 records.

I'm not that familiar with Bash.  Is this possible to do?  How do I get the output from the PHP script?

In pseudocode, I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
do:
  code = exec('.../script.php')
   # PHP script would print 0 if all records are processed or 1 if there is more to do
while (code != 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use bash?  You could probably do this with PHP:

```
while (true) {
  $output = exec('php otherscript.php', $out, $ret);
}
```

The $ret variable will contain the exit code of the script.

Comment: Good idea.  I decided to go this route. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763304/continually-running-php-script-using-bash/3764636#3764636 for my solution.

Answer (score 3):

$? gives you the exit code of a program in bash

You can do something ilke

```
while /bin/true; do
  php script.php
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
     echo "Error!";
     exit 1;
  fi
done
```

You can probably even do:

```
while php script.php; do
   echo "script returned success"
done
```

Comment: The second example will work fine, no need to use $? and test.

Comment: You don't have to use `/bin/true`, Bash has a `true` builtin. You don't need to use `$?` either. Your second example is the correct way.

Comment: In shell, programs must return 0 on success. Remember this for loops :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `until` loop to automatically test the exit status of the PHP script.

```
#!/bin/sh
until script.php
do
   :
done
```

The colon is merely a null operator, since you don't actually want to do anything else in the loop.
`until` while execute the command `script.php` until it returns zero (aka true).  If the script returned 0 to indicate not done instead of 1, you could use `while` instead of `until`.

The output of the PHP script would go to standard out and standard error, so you could wrap the invocation of the shell script with some I/O re-direction to stash the output in a file.  For example, if the script is called `loop.sh`, you'd just run:

```
./loop.sh > output.txt
```

though of course you can control the output file directly in the PHP script; you just have to remember to open the file for append.

You might want to ask a separate question about how to debug the PHP memory leak though :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
#!/bin/bash 

/usr/bin/php prg.php # run the script.
while [  $? != 0 ]; do # if ret val is non-zero => err occurred. So rerun.
  /usr/bin/php prg.php
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented solution in PHP instead as:

```
do {
    $code = 1;
    $output = array();
    $file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/script.php";
    exec("/usr/bin/php {$file}", $output, $code);

    $error = false;
    foreach ($output as $line) {
        if (stripos($line, 'error') !== false) {
            $error = true;
        }
        echo $line . "\n";
    }
} while ($code != 0 && !$error);
```